# can't restart openshift application

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge

I can't restart openshift application nodejs + postgres. I use free plan. Error in openshift online:

Could not stop Postgres
Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/{my_id}/postgresql

I found some advices to need to wait sometime and tech support will resolve it without my activity. But already three days service not work. And I asked on red hat bugzilla and my question is assigned to admin but there is no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. I thought users have not permission to kill process from openshift shell but they can.

```
ps aux|grep postgres
kill - pid
```

then restart app from openshift web console.